# Randomisation behaviour after cloning and fitting RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, random-seed

I have a basic nested CV loop, where an outer loop goes over an inner model-tuning step. My expectation is that each fold should draw a different random sample of hyperparameter values. However, in the example below, each fold ends up sampling the same values.

Imports and make dataset:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, KFold, cross_validate
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.base import clone

from scipy.stats import uniform
import numpy as np

X, y = make_classification(n_features=10, random_state=np.random.RandomState(0))
```

Nested CV loop:

```py
#Used for tuning the random forest:
rf_tuner = RandomizedSearchCV(
    RandomForestClassifier(random_state=np.random.RandomState(0)),
    param_distributions=dict(min_samples_split=uniform(0.1, 0.9)),
    n_iter=5,
    cv=KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=False),
    random_state=np.random.RandomState(0),
    n_jobs=1,
)

#Nested CV
for trn_idx, tst_idx in KFold(3).split(X, y):
    #'cloned' will now share the same RNG as 'rf_tuner'
    cloned = clone(rf_tuner)
    
    #This should be consuming the RNG of 'rf_tuner'
    cloned.fit(X[trn_idx], y[trn_idx])
    
    #Report hyperparameter values sampled in this fold
    display(cloned.cv_results_['params'])

    #<more code for nested CV, not shown>
```

Output:

```py
Fold 1/3:
[{'min_samples_split': 0.593},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.743},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.642},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.590},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.481}]

Fold 2/3:
[{'min_samples_split': 0.593},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.743},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.642},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.590},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.481}]

Fold 3/3:
[{'min_samples_split': 0.593},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.743},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.642},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.590},
 {'min_samples_split': 0.481}]
```

I start by instantiating a `RandomizedSearchCV` with a `RandomForestClassifier`. I set the `random_state=` of the search to a random state instance `np.random.RandomState(0)`.

For each pass of the outer loop, I `clone()` and `fit()` the search object - `cloned` should thus be using the *same* RNG as the original, mutating it at each pass. Each loop ought to yield a different sampling of hyperparameter values. However, as shown above, the hyperparameters sampled at each pass are identical. This suggests that each loop is starting with the same unmodified RNG rather than a mutated one.

The [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html#randomness) say that clones of estimators share the same random state instance:

> `b = clone(a)` [...] calling `a.fit` will consume `b`’s RNG, and calling `b.fit` will consume `a`’s RNG, since they are the same

What explains the absence of randomisation between folds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clone` performs a `deepcopy` on each non-estimator parameter ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9e38cd00d032f777312e639477f1f52f3ea4b3b7/sklearn/base.py#L104-L123)), and so in the case of a `RandomState` the clones will all have *different* `RandomState` objects all starting from the same state (in the sense of `get_state()`). So your example is expected.

I don't know offhand if this used to behave differently, or if the documentation has always been wrong in this point.

Comment: I see. So the original RNG doesn't get mutated directly, it is merely duplicated. Thanks for the explanation. I think that means if I want randomisation *between* folds, whilst making the script repeatable, I'd need to remove `random_state=` from the search object and instead globally set the random seed before I run the nested CV.